# Exception generated when updating table - java

Tags: java, sql, exception

The following code works - the table is updated (confirmed on the SQL server by looking at the table contents before and after the code is executed).

But, when I run the program in NetBeans and from a command line, an exception is caught by the CATCH block as soon as the "**rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQLquery);**" is executed.

I know this because the line "**System.out.println("Updated successfully!");**" just before the CATCH block is never executed. Nor is it executed if I move it up to just after "**rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQLquery);**".

The exception error is:

```
run:
The statement did not return a result set.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I can't understand what I have done wrong.

I did try using "**rs = stmt.executeUpdate(SQLquery);**" instead of "**rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQLquery);**", but NetBeans has the red exclamation mark with this note when I hover over it:

```
incompatible types
    required: ResultSet
    found: int
```

And if I compile it, NetBeans spits this out:

```
C:\Java\Example\src\example\Example.java:56: error: incompatible types
            rs = stmt.executeUpdate(SQLquery);
                                   ^
  required: ResultSet
  found:    int
1 error
```

**Grrr. I'm going nuts!
Please help!**

```
package example;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

class Example
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String host = "jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER1\\Primrose;databaseName=Primrose";
        String uName = "sa";
        String uPwd = "Pr1m@f@ct";

        String SQLquery = "";

        int totalFolders = 4;

        int getRecId = 0;
        String getUser = "";
        String getSection = "";
        String getKey = "";
        String getValue = "";
        String getExtraInfo = "";

        try
        {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPwd);
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            SQLquery = "SELECT * FROM _Registry WHERE (Section = 'RecIds' AND Key_ = '_Folders' AND User_ = 'sc_general')";

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQLquery);

            while (rs.next())
            {
                getRecId = rs.getInt("RecId");
                getUser = rs.getString("User_");
                getSection = rs.getString("Section");
                getKey = rs.getString("Key_");
                getValue = rs.getString("Value");
                getExtraInfo = rs.getString("ExtraInfo");

                getValue = getValue.trim();                         // Strip trailing spaces from string
                int newValue = Integer.parseInt(getValue) + 1;      // Convert string to number so I can add it to total folders
                newValue = newValue + totalFolders;                 // Change to total + existing value to write back to dB
                getValue = Integer.toString(newValue);              // Convert to string as required by the table
            }

            SQLquery = "UPDATE _Registry SET Value=" + getValue + " WHERE (RecId = 5 AND User_ = 'sc_general' AND Section = 'RecIds' AND Key_ = '_FOLDERS')";

            rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQLquery);

            rs.updateInt( "RecId", getRecId );
            rs.updateString( "User_", getUser );
            rs.updateString( "Section", getSection );
            rs.updateString( "Key_", getKey );
            rs.updateString( "Value", getValue );
            rs.updateString( "ExtraInfo", getExtraInfo );
            rs.updateRow();

            System.out.println("Updated successfully!");
        }

        catch ( SQLException err )  
        {
           System.out.println( err.getMessage( ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The function "stmt.executeUpdate(SQLquery);" returns an Integer, because you are not retrieving any data from the database. Try this:

```
Integer c = stmt.executeUpdate(SQLquery);
```

The Integer value indicates how many rows have been changed.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the javadocs for PreparedStatement for JRE that you're using.  `PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()` returns an int of the number of rows that were updated.  [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) is a link to the PreparedStatement docs.

Answer (score 1):

The executeUpdate returns an int, and not a resultset.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)

```
int nbUpdatedResult = stmt.executeUpdate(SQLquery);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that did it (and removing the rs.update lines)  :)

Answer (score 0):

The executeUpdate method returns number of rows affected, that's why you have this error.

So it's good to use this method. But you won't retrieve edited values.