# Error in .executeUpdate statement in Java Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

The code is showing the error in .executeUpdate statement. I tried to execute the sql statement through Java.
The error is showing in the line

```
rs = stmt.executeUpdate(upquery);
```

**And the error is :**
Incompatible Types
Found: int
Required: java.sql.ResultSet;

**Before starting the coding i imported certain things globally:**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
```

**Action code:**

```
try{
    int srl = Integer.parseInt(srlTF.getText());
    String date = dateTF.getText();
    String part = paTF.getText();
    float amt = Float.parseFloat(amtTF.getText());
    float exp = Float.parseFloat(expTF.getText());
    float pro = Float.parseFloat(proTF.getText());
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String usr = "root";
    String pwd = "root";
    String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/accounts?user="+usr+"&password="+pwd;
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
    stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT);
    String upquery = "insert into hostmargin_acc values(" + srl +","+ "'"+ date +","+ part +","+ amt +","+ exp +","+ pro + ");" ;
    rs = stmt.executeUpdate(upquery);
    msgLB.setText("BrO! Pwolichu! Save Chietu Kallan");
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: You have a mismatched apostrophe - `... "'"+ date +"," ....`

Answer (score 1):

`executeUpdate` returns the number of rows affected. Try

```
String upquery = "insert into hostmargin_acc values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement statement = 
              connection.prepareStatement(upquery,                                                                                               
                 ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT);
statement.setInt(1, srl);
// set more params...
int rows = statement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

executeUpdate() returns an integer to indicate whether the operation was successful or not. You are collecting the returned int variable in a variable of type ResultSet, hence the error.

similar problem you can look this link.
[[Exception generated when updating table - java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361962/exception-generated-when-updating-table-java][1])